# Running bpython inside a virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, bpython

I have created a virtualenv and installed [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) in it:

```
$ virtualenv alchemy
$ source alchemy/bin/activate
$ pip install sqlalchemy
```

`import` works in python:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> print sqlalchemy.__version__
0.9.7
```

But it does not work in [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/):

```
>>> import sqlalchemy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
```

Why can't bpython find the package installed in the virtualenv, even though it is executed after `source alchemy/bin/activate` is called?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`bpython` must be installed in the virtualenv, otherwise the external, system-wide bpython is called:

```
$ source alchemy/bin/activate
(alchemy)[ 10:34PM ]  [ adamatan@rubidium:/tmp ]
$ pip install bpython
...
$ alchemy/bin/bpython
--------------
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> print sqlalchemy.__version__
0.9.7
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this behaviour and access the /usr/lib bpython with the virtualenv?

Comment: Yes there is. You need to resource your activate script :

$ source alchemy/bin/activate
$ which bpython
/usr/bin/bpython
$ source alchemy/bin/activate
$ which bpython
alchemy/bin/bpython

Comment: If you leave and re-enter the venv after installing then the correct `bpython` will be found. No need to give the path to venv's `bin` dir any more.

Answer (score 8):

`bpython` has the python it was installed with hardcoded in its shebang.

You can manually edit it to make it use the current python. Open the script by running for instance `$ vi $(which bpython)`.

Then change the top line from eg. `#!/usr/bin/python3` to eg. `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

That should make it run using the venv's python. It's not supported officially by bpython but it has always worked for me on both Mac OS X and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Bpython must be installed with pip3 inside each virtualenv

```
$ virtualenv . 
$ source bin/activate 
$ pip3 install bpython
$ pip3 install sqlalchemy
$ bpython
```

`>>> import slqalchemy`

Answer (score 2):

Run bpython as module works for me

1. `mkdir workout && cd workout`
2. `venv shell --python=3.8`
3. Install your dependencies, e.g., `pipenv install gcloud`
4. `pipenv install bpython`
5. `python -m bpython`

```sh
python -m bpython
bpython version 0.21 on top of Python 3.8.5 /home/dennys/.local/share/virtualenvs/workout-qTtsVfjR/bin/python
>>> from gcloud import bigquery
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `bpython` does not exists in your venv bin folder you can find it with
`sudo find / -name bpython`. In my case it got installed in `~/.local/bin/`

```
$ source alchemy/bin/activate
$ pip install bpython
...
$ ~/.local/bin/bpython
```